# Div won't close

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

```
<div style="margin: 8px auto;text-align: center; clear: both;">
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-
prod/SNP_3094702_en_v0" style="max-width: 100%; />
</div>

^ // THIS IS THE DIV THAT WON'T CLOSE //
  // IT INSTEAD INCLUDES THE CONTENT BELOW //

<article class=">
<div class="category">
</div>
```

Hello! I own a wordpress blog and I'm trying to implement ads between posts, but I've run into a weird problem. This div won't close, no matter how many `</div>`'s I put after the img tag ends. It instead includes the whole rest of the page.

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I dont see the closing tag for the divs </div>

Comment: It's after the image tag? And sorry, I mean the first div in the paragraph. It includes the rest of the page (starting at article)

Comment: Just a heads up, `img` elements are *self-closing void tags* and require no *end tags*, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your given code of missing `"` in `img` tag style attribute

Error in code

```
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-
prod/SNP_3094702_en_v0" style="max-width: 100%;></div>
```

Correct code

```
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-
prod/SNP_3094702_en_v0" style="max-width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Superb! This is it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @ebkod.. please close the issue if you find the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin: 8px auto;text-align: center; clear: both;" id="ads">
<span id="close" style="float:right;">&times;  </span>
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-
prod/SNP_3094702_en_v0" style="max-width: 100%;">
</div>
<article class=">
<div class="category">
</div>
<script>
var close=document.GetElementById("close");
var ads=document.GetElementById("ads") ;
close.onclick = function() {
    ads.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

by click the close button it  hides the ads `<div>` .
i hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: what ? it is used to display image about ads  ,isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the tag is <img> and it's an empty element since it doesn't have any content and consequently no closing tag </img>

Comment: it  has  closing tag

Comment: yes sorry man i just copied his tag in the question .& got confused  .thank you for letting me know that.:)